# No output result displayed when run the code in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I need to make a code to move a single arm of a robot which contains three beams based on certain given `(x,y)` point and `theta0` has to start from `0`. Then `xd`, and `yd` should be calculated based on the following:

```cpp
xd = x - L cos(theta)
yd = y - L cos(theta)
```

where `L` is the first beam of single arm and where `theta` starts from `0` and `x` and `y` are entered.
Now, based on the calculated `xd` and `yd`, they will be used to calculate `theta1` and `theta2`.
These three angles should be sent to the servo motors.

However, When I enter the `x` and `y`, nothing is displayed! If you know some useful links that could help me in this problem, it will be really appreciated.

The serial code is:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>
#include <String.h>
#include <math.h>


Servo motor;
String content = "";
char character;

int yindex;
char End ;
String x,y;
int xt, yt;

float L0=297;
float L1=198;
float L2=165;

float theta0=0;
float theta1, theta2;

float xd,yd;
float xc,yc;




 void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  motor.attach(9,660,2600);  

  }

void loop() 
{
 if (Serial.available ()>0)
  {

     while(Serial.available()) 
     {
         character = Serial.read();
         content.concat(character);
         content += character;
         Serial.println (content);

         End=content.length();
         yindex= content.indexOf("y");

         x=content.substring(1,yindex);
         y=content.substring(yindex+1, End);

          Serial.println (x);
          Serial.println (y);


             xt=x.toInt();
           Serial.println(xt);

            yt=y.toInt();
            Serial.println(yt);



   for ( theta0=0; theta0<180; theta0+=0.1)
  {
      xd= xt-L0*cos(theta0); 
      yd= yt-L0*cos(theta0);

       theta2 = acos((sq(xd)+sq(yd)- sq(L1)-sq(L2))/(2*L1*L2));
       theta1 = asin((L2*sin(theta2))/sqrt(sq(xd)+sq(yd)))+atan(yd/xd);

      Serial.println("The value of theta2 is : ");
      Serial.println(theta2);


      Serial.println("The value of theta1 is : ");
      Serial.println(theta1);


      xc = L0*cos(theta0) + L1*cos(theta1) + L2*cos(theta2);
      yc= L0*sin(theta0) + L1*sin(theta1) + L2*sin(theta2);


      Serial.println("The value of the calculated x is : ");
      Serial.println(xc);
      Serial.println("The value of the calculated y is : ");
     Serial.println(yc);
     Serial.println("The value of  theta0:");
      Serial.println(theta0);

      theta0=theta0*(180/3.14);
      theta1=theta1*(180/3.14);
      theta2=theta2*(180/3.14);

      if (theta1<=-180 && theta1>=0 && theta2>=0 && theta2 <=-180)
      {
           break;
       } 

     }



  }
 }

     content="";
 }
```

Comment: Can you give us any more information? Do the values get sent to the arduino? Your question is very vague.

Comment: @jamolnng, when I run the program, it is supposed to use those equations to calculate the entered value of X and Y and theta 1 and 2 to make the arm moves. However, When I enter the X and Y, nothing has been displayed!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems here. You should approach problems like this by testing each step of the solution at a time, so you don't end up with a big mess. First, you need to make sure you're reading the string in properly.

That part of the code is not working correctly because the `{}` surrounding the `while(Serial.available())` loop are not in the right spot. Also, you're appending the new character twice by using both `+=` and `concat`. Here's a simple fix to get the string correctly. The delay is to allow for the next byte to be available so it doesn't exit the loop prematurely.

```
  content="";
  while (Serial.available() < 1) {}
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    character = Serial.read();
    content += character;
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.print("content = "); Serial.println (content);
```

Next you need to parse the values for x and y out of the string. There are a couple problems here as well. I don't think you want to use integers for x and y, so you need a way to interpret the string as a float. Here is how you can parse the values into floats.

```
  End=content.length();
  yindex= content.indexOf("y");

  x=content.substring(1,yindex);
  y=content.substring(yindex+1, End);

  Serial.print("x = "); Serial.println (x);
  Serial.print("y = "); Serial.println (y);

  char xbuf[10] = "";
  x.toCharArray(xbuf, 10);
  xt = atof(xbuf);
  Serial.print("xt = "); Serial.println(xt);

  char ybuf[10] = "";
  y.toCharArray(ybuf, 10);
  yt = atof(ybuf);
  Serial.print("yt = "); Serial.println(yt);
```

That should be enough help to get you moving along. There are some problems in your math later in the code, but that should be easier to work out after you have working print statements. Note - the format this code is expecting from the serial monitor are of the format `x0.34y0.678` where `0.34` is the value of `x` and `0.678` is the value of `y`.